# zsh redirection with `multios` on does not redirect stdout multiple times

Tags: shell, zsh, io-redirection

Assume I am in a folder with file `a` but no `b`. Then `ls a b` will have output `a` goes to stdout and `ls: cannot access b:` goes to stderr.

Now, in my understanding, with `multios` on, the command `ls a b >output1 2>&1 >output2` will

1. redirect stdout to `output1`.
2. copy stderr to stdout, so stderr also goes to `output1`
3. duplicate stdout to `output2` as `multios` is on

So the total effect is that stdout goes to both `output1` and `output2` while stderr goes to `output1`

However, I cannot find in `output1` the stdout part (the file `a`). What is wrong with my understanding?

Strangely, If I added another redirection, the `multios` options will have the effect:

with `ls a b >output1 >output2 2>&1 >output3`, the stdout goes to `output1`, `output2`, `output3` at the same time. This conforms to my understanding.

Comment: Which zsh version you used? 5.4.2 works for me.

Comment: Yes the version matters. I used 5.0.2. I retried on version 5.4.2 and it works as expected. Thanks.